# Getting missing return at end of function while using return Golang

Tags: go

When i'm running my code, the output tells me that i'm missing a return statement even when i'm using one.

This is my code:

```
func uitchecken(product string, balance float64, voltarief float64, instaptarief float64) float64 {
    
// This part of the code makes a string into a float64

    if s, err := strconv.ParseFloat(product, 64); err == nil {
        result1 := s

        result := balance - (result1 * voltarief) + instaptarief
        return result
    }
}
```

The idea of this code is to get 1 string and 3 float64 in it then do a little bit af math and returns the value in the main function.

Comment: The return statement is in a conditional. If the conditional does not hold, what the function should return is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

If `err != nil`, your function literally returns nothing.

I would say, the code as presented in an ani-pattern in Go (though, it may indeed occasionally be useful) because a good style in Go is to have the main program flow to be "on the main line", like in

```golang
val, err := doSomething()
if err != nil {
  // Handle the error out of the way
}

// "Normal" flow dealing with `val` is on the main line.
```

In your particular case, I cannot see why parsing of `product` may not fail.

If you are *sure* it cannot, make the code panic, like with:

```golang
func mustParseFloat(s string) float64 {
  s, err := strconv.ParseFloat(product, 64)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return s
}

func uitchecken(product string, balance float64, voltarief float64, instaptarief float64) float64 {
  result1 := mustParseFloat(product)
  return balance - (result1 * voltarief) + instaptarief
}
```

Still, given the names of your variables, I sense the ["code smell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) with your original example: it's *strange* to see the variable `product` contain a string which is needed to be parsed while the rest of the variables participating in the same calculation are `float64`s; *it feels* like you'd better try to parse that string somewhere way closer to the point it was *received* from the user (or the client)—with the possible parsing error checked and reported to that user/client right there.
In other words, it's a good engineering practice to first [validate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation) the user's input and then operate on the known-to-be-valid data.

Answer (score 0):

Return after if

````
func uitchecken(product string, balance float64, voltarief float64, instaptarief float64) float64 {
    
// This part of the code makes a string into a float64

    if s, err := strconv.ParseFloat(product, 64); err == nil {
        result1 := s

        result := balance - (result1 * voltarief) + instaptarief
        return result
    }
    return something <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```
````